# jquery callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I need to be able to have a callback on execution of a function after ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   execute function 1, only when finish
      do function 2
});
```

what is the good way to do that ?

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: What is the "something" you're trying, is it asynchronous?

Comment: i have no sure way to know the function 1 is finish before doing finction 2

Comment: Are you talking about .queue() ?

Comment: What is function 1? In almost all cases, you know it's done just because the control came back to you and went to function 2. You mean it's asyncronous then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following execute once the document has been loaded:

```
$(function(){
    DoSomething();
});

function DoSomething()
{
    SomethingElse(); // depends what you're doing in DoSomething()
}

function SomethingElse()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is single-threaded.  Nothing happens simultaneously.  However, if fn1 is an async call, the thread will execute fn2 often before fn1's return value is ready.  That's what makes JavaScript "racy."

If you have multiple aysnc calls in a series, then you either have to manage a series of NESTED callbacks or make a queue using the Active Object pattern.  jQuery has one (mentioned). I wrote a library that does this called proto-q: http://code.google.com/p/proto-q/

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a good way. you can use: `(function(){});` if you are not using javascripts libs other than jQuery for ready

Answer (score 0):

you can let function1 call a second function then the third one, and so on. but it is allways line by line