# nest functions to run in sequence

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I know this is basic but after looking at multiple resources (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813191/jquery-callback/3813223#3813223)) I'm stuck. How do I nest `functionTwo` so that it runs only after `functionOne` is complete? Here are my attempts. (I actually want to do something more complicated in functionTwo, I'm just simplifying for this test case.)

```
$(function () {
    functionOne();
});

function functionOne() {
    $(".foo:first").attr('id','bar');
    functionTwo();
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log($('.foo:first').attr('id'));     // log the new id: 'bar'
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/t9pAR/)

This works, but are they running independently? When I [put a timeout on the first function](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/t9pAR/2/), nothing gets logged (unless that's a separate error).

Then I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    functionOne();
});

function functionOne() {
    $(".foo:first").attr('id', 'bar', function () {
            functionTwo();
        });
    }

function functionTwo() {
    console.log($('.foo:first').attr('id'));
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/t9pAR/3/)

Nothing gets logged. Maybe a callback can't be a parameter if `.attr`

Then:

```
  $(function () {
      $.when.functionOne().done(function () {
          functionTwo();
      });
  });

  function functionOne() {
      $(".foo:first").attr('id', 'bar');
  }

  function functionTwo() {
      console.log($('.foo:first').attr('id'));
  }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/t9pAR/3/)

Nothing gets logged. I don't think `.when` and `.done` are supposed to be used this way.

So how should I nest these?

Comment: `setTimeout(function functionOne() {` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: doesn't seem to be a reason why the first one wouldn't work.  And no, `attr` doesn't take a callback.  And you're right, `when` doesn't work like that.

Comment: What's wrong with the 1st one?

Comment: can't chain a non jquery method to `$.when` you pass it as argument

Comment: I can see the log in chrome.

Comment: @Rocket How can I do what I'm trying to do with setTimeout -- basically, how can I tell that functionTwo is 'waiting' for functionOne? [Update: OK I see your answer]

Comment: @numbers1311407 `attr()` can take callback , will loop over all elements and within callback you return new value for attribute in first argument

Comment: in chrome, i see the 1st jsfiddle log everything correctly.

Comment: @nathanbweb: You need to call `setTimeout` *inside* the function.  In your example, `functionOne` didn't exist so you were getting an error.

Comment: @charlietfl my intention wasn't to split hairs over the definition of "callback".  `attr` does not accept a function which "calls back" on completion: how about that?

Comment: @numbers1311407 works for me, wasn't part of the API originally...but comes in handy sometimes.....was just throwing it in theer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st one is the way to go here.

```
$(function () {
    functionOne();
});

function functionOne() {
    $(".foo:first").attr('id','bar');
    functionTwo();
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log($('.foo:first').attr('id'));     // log the new id: 'bar'
}
```

`.attr` is synchronous, so this works as expected.

In your `setTimeout` example (http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/t9pAR/2/), you are using `setTimeout` incorrectly.

```
setTimeout(function functionOne() {}, 2000)
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  This will create a function, and run it after 2 seconds.  The name `functionOne` will *only* exist inside the function's own scope.

You probably wanted this:

```
$(function () {
    functionOne();
});

function functionOne() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".foo:first").attr('id','bar');
        functionTwo();
    }, 2000);
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log($('.foo:first').attr('id'));     // log the new id: 'bar'
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/t9pAR/6/

Answer (score 1):

Why not try returning the function you want to call second.

```
function functionOne() {
    $(".foo:first").attr('id','bar');
    return functionTwo();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9pAR/5/

Comment: How is this any different from his 1st example?  What's the point of the `return` here?  How does that fix/change anything?

Comment: It provides the ability to pass back success/failure messages back to the caller. 1 as it stands gives no feedback to calling functions.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question here, though.